# Compilation error C4715

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile the code below, but it fails with error C4715. Can someone please help me:

```
bool addManaRatio(const Real &ratio)
{
    if(ratio<0)return false;
    addMana(ratio * maxMana);
    return 0;                       <<<FIX THANKS OliPro007
}

const Real getManaRatio()
{
    if(maxMana<=0)return 0;
    return Real(mana)/Real(maxMana);
}## Heading ##
```

This is  code for a Mana function, that cannot be compiled for some reason.

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask correctly, and edit your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not return anything in `addManaRatio` if ratio is not less than 0... A quick google gives this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6deaf4k9.aspx